# Android Facebook Sync doesn't activate in System"Accounts/Sync" Setting

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync, facebook, accounts

I re-added my Facebook app account to "Accounts and Sync" (in System Settings) but it won't activate sync. The button stays grey.
Sync of overall phone is on. This is after a delete and reinstall of the App.

I have Huawei m931 running Android 4.0.4. Here is what I did:

1. Reinstalled app on phone, after clearing cache+ data, signing out of chrome.
   (not sure correct procedure).
2. New username/Email of my Facebook account is same as my **primary** Gmail/Chrome email address.
   [image: screen shot of Accounts Sync in my phone]

Of note is I have 2 gmail, and 1 Yahoo accounts on phone.
Also, the phone's number is used in both gmail accounts for security alerts (don't know if is relevant)

**Help!, am new at this**

Comment: Please provide more details of the error. Did you remove the old account? Are you adding the new via email address or username?

Comment: I added new account after removing existing one. I changed username of FB app to phone #. But my primary gmail email is in account email.of fb.